# PTIJ: What is the significance of the mitzvah to multiply in Peru?

Tags: purim-torah-in-jest

Genesis 1:28:

> וַיְבָ֣רֶךְ אֹתָם֮ אֱלֹהִים֒ וַיֹּ֨אמֶר לָהֶ֜ם אֱלֹהִ֗ים פְּר֥וּ וּרְב֛וּ וּמִלְא֥וּ אֶת־הָאָ֖רֶץ וְכִבְשֻׁ֑הָ וּרְד֞וּ בִּדְגַ֤ת הַיָּם֙ וּבְע֣וֹף הַשָּׁמַ֔יִם וּבְכָל־חַיָּ֖ה הָֽרֹמֶ֥שֶׂת עַל־הָאָֽרֶץ׃
>
> God blessed them and God said to them, “[In] Peru, increase; fill the earth and master it; and rule the fish of the sea, the birds of the sky, and all the living things that creep on earth.”
>
> *(courtesy of Sefaria)*

My understanding is that Gan Eden is somewhere near modern-day Iraq, which is very far from Peru (a thirty-three-hour plane trip, according to Google). So why did God choose Peru for this holy mitzvah? Especially to only take us to Cana'an (still nineteen hours away)? Or maybe I'm misunderstanding this verse?

---

## This question is [Purim Torah](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Purim_Torah) and is not intended to be taken completely seriously. See the [Purim Torah policy](https://judaism.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/797/).

Comment: I don't have a good or clever answer to this, but my first three children were born in Peru so chazak u baruch

Comment: He’s testing us to see if we’ll listen to him and rule and increase in Peru, so obviously we have failed.

Comment: What are we supposed to do outside of Peru, then?

Comment: @MauriceMizrahi we can still do Mitzvos, it’s just not a mitzva to multiply or rule.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

One is supposed to pray for a בן זכר, and since Lima beans are served at a shalom zachar, Peru is the ideal place to have children.

Answer (score 3):

וַיָּבֹ֣אוּ אוֹפִ֔ירָה וַיִּקְח֤וּ מִשָּׁם֙ זָהָ֔ב אַרְבַּע־מֵא֥וֹת וְעֶשְׂרִ֖ים כִּכָּ֑ר וַיָּבִ֖אוּ אֶל־הַמֶּ֥לֶךְ שְׁלֹמֹֽה׃ {פ}
They came to Ophir; there they obtained gold in the amount of four hundred and twenty talents, which they delivered to King Solomon.

https://www.sefaria.org/I_Kings.9.28

Ophir according to Rav Belsky is reffering to Peru. Peru is known to have lots of gold.
The Radak tiches urvu to mean sustain. Rav Shlomo Cynamon explains that part of peru urvu is to sustain the children. Therefore it's befitting to have children in Peru where there's lots of Gold, and one can easily sustain his children.

Comment: This is more true than you can possibly know.

Comment: @יהושעק which part?

Comment: The ease of parnasah in Peru

Answer (score 3):

Over two-thirds of Peru's land mass is taken up by the Amazon rainforest, which is largely uninhabited. And as it says in Yishayau 45:18,
"כִּ֣י כֹ֣ה אָֽמַר־יְ֠הֹוָ֠ה בּוֹרֵ֨א הַשָּׁמַ֜יִם ה֣וּא הָאֱלֹהִ֗ים יֹצֵ֨ר הָאָ֤רֶץ וְעֹשָׂהּ֙ ה֣וּא כֽוֹנְנָ֔הּ לֹא־תֹ֥הוּ בְרָאָ֖הּ לָשֶׁ֣בֶת יְצָרָ֑הּ אֲנִ֥י יְהֹוָ֖ה וְאֵ֥ין עֽוֹד׃"

"For thus says the Lord that created the heavens; God himself that formed the earth and made it; he has established it, he did not create it a waste land, he formed it to be inhabited: I am the Lord; and there is none else."

As we can see, the original commandment was for Jews to populate the Amazon Rainforest. [Some actually tried](https://www.jewishvirtuallibrary.org/iquitos) to very limited success at best.

Moyses Pinto, originally from Tetuán, Morocco, [gives a full account here.](http://www.moroccan-jews-in-amazonia.com/memoires.php)